# Select query to retrieve data from SQL Server CE table of row number i to row number j

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am using Visual Studio 2008. In a SQL Server CE table, I want to select rows from 1 to 10 at first button click event, 2 to 11 at next click event.

I went through given below SQL query

```
SELECT column1, column2....columnN
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN val-1 AND val-2;
```

In this query instead of `val_1` and `val_2`, what can I write so I'll get rows from 1 to 10 later 2 to 11, later 3 to 12?

Help me correct my code...

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE SerialNo BETWEEN i AND j", con1); 

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("i",i.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("j",j.ToString());

SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

DataTable table = new DataTable();

while (reader.Read())
{
    s1 = reader.GetString(10);
}

reader.Close();
i++;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question exactly? What is not working? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Check my answer, I think it fills Your requirements.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

For example You can Create for loop for this which will increment by 10 like below:

```
for (int i=0, j=9; i < YourMaxValue; i+=10, j+=10)
{
  string query = "SELECT * FROM Table1 Where SerialNo BETWEEN @val1 AND @val2"
  SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, con1);
  cmd.Parameters.Clear();
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@val1",SqlDbType.Integer).Value = i;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@val2",SqlDbType.Integer).Value = j;
  ...
}
```